# Rails route structure for managing tags

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I'm hoping someone could vet my route structure as I've really been struggling with getting something that feels right. Right now I have this nested resource structure:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  concern :configable do
    resource :config, only: %i[edit update]
  end

  resources :tags do
    scope module: 'tags' do
      resources :versions,
                concerns: :configable,
                shallow: true,
                shallow_path: 'tags',
                shallow_prefix: 'tag' do
        scope module: 'versions' do
          resources :files,
                    shallow: true,
                    shallow_path: 'versions',
                    shallow_prefix: 'version'
          resources :snippets,
                    shallow: true,
                    shallow_path: 'versions',
                    shallow_prefix: 'version'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

```
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
        tag_version_files GET    /tags/versions/:version_id/files(.:format)                                               tags/versions/files#index
                          POST   /tags/versions/:version_id/files(.:format)                                               tags/versions/files#create
     new_tag_version_file GET    /tags/versions/:version_id/files/new(.:format)                                           tags/versions/files#new
    edit_tag_version_file GET    /tags/versions/files/:id/edit(.:format)                                                  tags/versions/files#edit
         tag_version_file GET    /tags/versions/files/:id(.:format)                                                       tags/versions/files#show
                          PATCH  /tags/versions/files/:id(.:format)                                                       tags/versions/files#update
                          PUT    /tags/versions/files/:id(.:format)                                                       tags/versions/files#update
                          DELETE /tags/versions/files/:id(.:format)                                                       tags/versions/files#destroy
     tag_version_snippets GET    /tags/versions/:version_id/snippets(.:format)                                            tags/versions/snippets#index
                          POST   /tags/versions/:version_id/snippets(.:format)                                            tags/versions/snippets#create
  new_tag_version_snippet GET    /tags/versions/:version_id/snippets/new(.:format)                                        tags/versions/snippets#new
 edit_tag_version_snippet GET    /tags/versions/snippets/:id/edit(.:format)                                               tags/versions/snippets#edit
      tag_version_snippet GET    /tags/versions/snippets/:id(.:format)                                                    tags/versions/snippets#show
                          PATCH  /tags/versions/snippets/:id(.:format)                                                    tags/versions/snippets#update
                          PUT    /tags/versions/snippets/:id(.:format)                                                    tags/versions/snippets#update
                          DELETE /tags/versions/snippets/:id(.:format)                                                    tags/versions/snippets#destroy
  edit_tag_version_config GET    /tags/versions/:version_id/config/edit(.:format)                                         tags/configs#edit
       tag_version_config PATCH  /tags/versions/:version_id/config(.:format)                                              tags/configs#update
                          PUT    /tags/versions/:version_id/config(.:format)                                              tags/configs#update
             tag_versions GET    /tags/:tag_id/versions(.:format)                                                         tags/versions#index
                          POST   /tags/:tag_id/versions(.:format)                                                         tags/versions#create
          new_tag_version GET    /tags/:tag_id/versions/new(.:format)                                                     tags/versions#new
         edit_tag_version GET    /tags/versions/:id/edit(.:format)                                                        tags/versions#edit
              tag_version GET    /tags/versions/:id(.:format)                                                             tags/versions#show
                          PATCH  /tags/versions/:id(.:format)                                                             tags/versions#update
                          PUT    /tags/versions/:id(.:format)                                                             tags/versions#update
                          DELETE /tags/versions/:id(.:format)                                                             tags/versions#destroy
                     tags GET    /tags(.:format)                                                                          tags#index
                          POST   /tags(.:format)                                                                          tags#create
                  new_tag GET    /tags/new(.:format)                                                                      tags#new
                 edit_tag GET    /tags/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                 tags#edit
                      tag GET    /tags/:id(.:format)                                                                      tags#show
                          PATCH  /tags/:id(.:format)                                                                      tags#update
                          PUT    /tags/:id(.:format)                                                                      tags#update
                          DELETE /tags/:id(.:format)                                                                      tags#destroy
```

I'm wondering if A) there's a more succinct way to get that structure with a combinations of namespace/scope and B) if perhaps that structure is not the best way to go about it. I like it because it keeps the directory structure clean but am very open to cleaning it up. Not sure if having resources under a path prefix (in the case of versions) qualifies as breaking the more-than-one-nested-resource deep advice I've gotten from many people.